# What episode of Star Trek is this creature from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, character-identification, episode-identification

[image: canine-looking creature with a horn]

This little guy has been circulating around the internet today, claiming he's an alien from *Star Trek*. Do we know if that's true? And what episode of *ToS* is he from? What is he?

Comment: How do you not know about the unidog? >.>

Comment: That dog seems like it does not like being dressed up.

Comment: It's the opposite of a service dog for the anxious.

Comment: You wouldn't be happy if someone tied half a banana and some sparklers to your head, either.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is from "The Enemy Within", episode 5 of season 1 of *Star Trek: The Original Series*. The creature is never named in the episode, although the planet they found it on is stated to be Alpha 177, so Memory Alpha calls it the "Alfa 177 Canine".

Here's a screenshot from the same episode with Kirk holding the same creature:

[image: Spock and Kirk, Kirk is holding the horned canine creature]

Technically, your screenshot shows the evil twin of the creature Kirk is holding. The whole premise of this episode is a transporter malfunction that splits this creature and then Kirk into good and evil twins.

The scene that your screenshot probably comes from was [transcribed by chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/5.htm) as follows:

> [Transporter room]
>   KIRK: What is it, Scotty?
>   SCOTT: Transporter breakdown. Continue circuit testing. We beamed up this animal and, well, look for yourself. It's in this specimen case. (opens lid to reveal angry pink animal)
>   KIRK: Yes?
>   SCOTT: A few seconds after they sent this one up through the transporter, that duplicate appeared. Except it's not a duplicate, it's an opposite. Two of the same animal, but different. One gentle, this. One mean and fierce, that. Some kind of savage, ferocious opposite. Captain, we don't dare send Mister Sulu and the landing party up. If this should happen to a man.
>   KIRK: Oh, my.

Comment: it is so cute! Not like a dog with some attachments at all. I was hoping to see a better CGI version in the Remastered episodes.

Comment: @PhasedOut Same, this is one of the few moments in ToS where I had to stop and laugh at how low the budget must have been. Still enjoyed the episode though.

Comment: can you imagine being an actor on the show, and being handed this animal to work with. Now I am inspired to read some of the casts memoirs to see how much disbelief suspension was handled. This one by far is my favorite - second place is the Beauregard puppet plant seen in the episode TOS: The Man Trap, that lives in the botanical garden of the Enterprise.

Comment: I had always known it as the "space spaniel".

Comment: @Ixrec: "at how low the budget must have been" - less than a question of budget, this was more a question of technological progress. CGI didn't exist, and animatronics were nowhere near what they became a few decades later.

Comment: There are other things in this episode attributable to the low budget. Ever wondered why they would rather let the away team freeze on the planet surface while repairing the transporter than send a shuttle? Well, there was no money left to build a shuttle model.

Comment: I was raised to believe shuttles hadn't been invented until after episode five.

Comment: @JörgWMittag If you can't handwave the shuttle issue, you have no business watching Star Trek :-)

Comment: really, Kirk is the one to say "Oh, my." ?

Comment: @MajorStackings Shuttles were in the script from the beginning. Transporters were a kludgy hack to avoid the budget costs (and, well, watching a shuttle descend on a planet in every episode), and as is often the case, those "savings" bit back - every other episode had to invent some reason why transporters don't work in that particular situation (especially in TNG).

Comment: @Luaan Here's a bit more info regarding the Shuttle Craft: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100572/in-tos-the-enemy-within-why-didnt-the-enterprise-use-shuttles-after-the-trans

Comment: @JörgWMittag: less of a budget issue than a plot hole. when i saw it i was wondering why they could not beam down shelter and heating material, after all that should not be affected by the malfunction. and if the shelter gets duplicated: bonus :-)

Comment: @eMBee Of course it wouldn't be safe to use the shelter's evil twin...assuming you can even figure out which one is evil.

Answer (score 9):

This wonderful creature is known as the "Alfa 177 Canine", seen in the Star Trek: TOS Episode *The Enemy Within*.

More information can be found on Memory Alpha at the following link: [Alfa 177 Canine](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Unnamed_non-humanoids_(23rd_century))